# Efficient SQL query with having and group by

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I am wondering whether there is better solution in terms of efficiency to write this SQL query,your help is greatly appreciated.

Question: 
Find out makers who produce only the models of the same type, and the number of those models exceeds 1. Deduce: maker, type

The answer I have is:

```
Select distinct P1.maker, P1.type 
from Product AS P1 join 
              (select maker 
               from Product 
               group by maker 
               having count(distinct type)=1 
               and count(model) > 1) as P2 
on P1.maker = P2.maker
```

which gives result since D produce only printer with more than 1 model:

```
maker   type
  D    Printer
```

I attempt to use subquery part like :

```
select maker,type 
from Product 
group by maker 
having count(distinct type)=1 and count(model) > 1
```

gives error like:

> Column 'Product.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It is confusing to me since it appears that type is used in aggregate function count. It appears that valid column in select should be in group by or aggreagate function.

The Producer table is something like the following:

```
maker   type    model
B        PC     1121
A        PC     1232
A        PC     1233
E        PC     1260
A      Printer  1276
D      Printer  1288
A      Laptop   1298
C      Laptop   1321
A      Printer  1401
A      Printer  1408
D      Printer  1433
E      Printer  1434
B      Laptop   1750
A      Laptop   1752
E        PC     2112
E        PC     2113
```

Comment: `type` is not used in the group by, or in the aggregates that you are _displaying_.  Doesnt count to have it in the `having`

Comment: The question you are attempting to answer is unclear.  If Maker1 produces models a,b, and c, and Maker2 produces model b only, and Maker3 produces models b, c and d, what should the query return?

Comment: maker2. maker can produce three different type of products and each type of product has different model. the query is trying to find the maker that only produce one type of product (like printer) while that type of product has more than one model to choose from (like 1288 and 1433 for D)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select maker, max(type)
from Product 
group by maker 
having count(distinct type)=1 
and count(model) > 1
```

Having type in a aggregate function in the having does nothing.  When you get that error the problem is in the select.  You have grouped by maker, what happens if there is more than one type for a maker?  Which type should be displayed?  Sql doesn't know so you have to aggregate type or add it to the group by.  In your case, since the entire point is to only return rows with a single distinct type, we can just use max to return the type.

Comment: Please check my comments above it.

Comment: select maker, max(type) from Product group by maker 
having count(distinct type)=1 
and count(model) > 1 @Vulcronos

Comment: It is faster than mine and it appears just add a aggregate function to it will do the job